# Extracting specific elements from hash

Tags: perl, hash

```
my %hash = {
    'student1' => {
        'Name' => 'aaa',
        'Age'  => '20',
        'Subjects' => ['Maths','Science']
    },
    'student2' => {
        'Name' => 'bbb',
        'Age'  => '22',
        'Subjects' => ['English','Science']
    }
}
my $hashRef = \%hash;
```

how do i extract the second subject name from this using hashref ?

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration of `%hash` is incorrect, do this instead:

```
my %hash = (
    'student1' => {
        'Name' => 'aaa',
        'Age'  => '20',
        'Subjects' => ['Maths','Science']
    },
    'student2' => {
        'Name' => 'bbb',
        'Age'  => '22',
        'Subjects' => ['English','Science']
    }
);
```

Note the parens instead og brace.

Then to get the second subject :

```
say $hashRef->{student1}{Subjects}[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong, { } creates a hashref and you are storing it in a hash. You should do:

```
my %hash = (
    'student1' => {
        'Name' => 'aaa',
        'Age'  => '20',
        'Subjects' => ['Maths','Science']
    },
    'student2' => {
        'Name' => 'bbb',
        'Age'  => '22',
        'Subjects' => ['English','Science']
    }
);

my $hashRef = \%hash;
```

or even better:

```
my $hashref = {
    student1 => { ... },
    student2 => { ... },
};
```

Then you can access with:

```
$hashRef->{student2}->{Subjects}[1]
```

Comment: for (keys %$hashRef) { 
    print "$_ is the student\n"; 
    print "\t Name : $$hashRef{$_}{Name}\n"; 
    print "\t Second Subject : $$hashRef{$_}{Subjects}[1]\n"; 

}

Answer (score 0):

Subjects are an array reference inside a hash inside a hash.

```
$hashRef->{student1}{Subjects}[1]
```

Also, do not use curly brackets to initilize a hash, they create an anonymous hash. Use round parentheses:

```
my %hash = ( ... );
```

Comment: printing this would be " print $hashRef {student 1}{subjects}[1] ; ?

Comment: @user2742160: No, you should not drop the arrow `->`. Also, unquoted spaces are not allowed in hash keys.